# Message charset

Tags: java, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

How do I get the charset from javax.mail.Message object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail API should convert the data to Unicode for you, so at the time when you can call the getter for the text, the original charset shouldn't matter.

But if you really need it, then call `getContentType()` and look for `charset=`. If it's there, then that's the encoding. If it isn't there, then the charset should be `US-ASCII` (7 bit).

Answer (score 1):

The `MimeMessage` class has a [method](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getEncoding()) which returns the transfer encoding.

*Edit:* But, as [Aaron correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755129/message-charset#answer-1755155), you normally shouldn't have to worry.